# Ruby on Rails: Rendering the application.html.erb file in my views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, actionview

This is my `application.html.erb` file in my `app/views/layouts` folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                                       "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <%= link_to "sample app", '#', id: "logo" %>
          <nav>
            <ul class="nav pull-right">
              <li><%= link_to "Home",    '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Help",    '#' %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign in", '#' %></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is my `home.html.erb` file in a separate `app/views/static_pages` folder:

```
<div class="center hero-unit">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

  <h2>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </h2>

  <%= link_to "Sign up now!", '#', class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</div>

 <%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "Rails"), 'http://rubyonrails.org/' %>
```

For some reason, when running the server, the only code that gets displayed is from the home.html.erb file. Why isn't the code of `application.html.erb` file displayed?
This is my `config/routes.rb` file, if it is of help:

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
   get "static_pages/home"
   get "static_pages/help"
   get "static_pages/about"
end
```

I am aware that there are similar queries on StackOverflow, though none of them could answer my question. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: What's the page source code showing?

Comment: You mention `application.html` and `home.html` in your question.  For layout to work the extension needs to be `.erb`, can you please double check that?

Comment: did you have a look at the .log file? what does it say?

Comment: Strangely, when I add .erb to the current file name (home.html), I get the following error message:  Missing template static_pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/program/projects/sample_app/app/views"

Comment: with regards to jason328's question, this is what the source code is showing when I load the page in my browser:
<div class="center hero-unit">
  <h1>Welcome to the Sample App</h1>

  <h2>
    This is the home page for the
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
    sample application.
  </h2>

  <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary" href="#">Sign up now!</a>
</div>

<a href="http://rubyonrails.org/"><img alt="Rails" src="/assets/rails.png" /></a>

Comment: This is my log file report:  Started GET "/static_pages/home" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-09-08 21:56:14 +0200
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb (1.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 6.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

Comment: Thanks - I solved the problem, after considering vinodadhikary's comment. The mistake was that I called the file application.html.erb explicitly, while it seems I should only have called the file application.html. Ruby seems to add the .erb extension automatically.

Comment: If you think that _Ruby_ is adding the `.erb` extension, then you should learn to distinguish between Ruby and _Rails_. You should also create an answer and mark it as correct.